# Gradient of a forth order scalar function with respect to a Matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative, matrix-equations

I'm trying to take the gradient of the following function w.r.t A:

$$
f(A) = ||AC_YA^T - C_R||_F^2
$$

I tried the following:

$$
f(A) = trace((AC_YA^T - C_R)^T(AC_YA^T - C_R)) = trace(AC_Y^TA^TAC_YA^T) - trace(A C_Y^T A^T C_R) - trace(C_R^T AC_Y A^T) + trace(C_R^T C_R)
$$

Now using identities found on wiki for matrix diff found in the following link:

[Matric Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus).

I have no issues differentiating the second, third, and obviously forth terms w.r.t A.

The only issue is with the first term which is 
$$
trace(AC_Y^TA^TAC_YA^T)
$$
Now by the commute property I can easily rewrite the previous terms as follows:

$$
g(A) = trace(C_Y^T \Psi C_Y \Psi ^T)
$$
Where $$\Psi = A^T A$$
Keep in mind that $C_Y$ and $C_R$ are covariance matrices, so they are symmetric.

But how to take the derivative of g(A).

I tried taking the chain rule where, but wasn't sure how to use it.
It appeared as if I'll end up with a tensor. I'm definitely sure that the answer should be a matrix though, since the main function F(A) is just a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=(AC_YA^T-C_R)$, then write the function in terms of the Frobenius product (:) and take its differential 
$$\eqalign{
 f &= M:M \cr
df &= 2\,M:dM \cr
   &= 2\,M:(dA\,C_YA^T + AC_Y\,dA^T) \cr
   &= 2\,M:dA\,C_YA^T \,+\, 2\,M:AC_Y\,dA^T \cr
   &= 2\,M:dA\,C_YA^T \,+\, 2\,M^T:dA\,C_Y^TA^T \cr
   &= 2\,MAC_Y^T:dA \,+\, 2\,M^TAC_Y:dA \cr
   &= 2\,(MAC_Y^T + M^TAC_Y):dA \cr
}$$
Since $\,df=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}):dA$, the derivative must be
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial A}  &= 2\,(MAC_Y^T + M^TAC_Y) \cr
  &= 2\,\Big((AC_YA^T-C_R)AC_Y^T + (AC_YA^T-C_R)^TAC_Y\Big) \cr
  &= 2\,\big(AC_YA^TAC_Y^T-C_RAC_Y^T + AC_Y^TA^TAC_Y-C_R^TAC_Y\big) \cr
}$$
If you like, you can replace the Frobenius product with the trace, since $\,A\!:\!B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$.  However, I prefer the Frobenius product because it has nice algebraic properties.

It is commutative, distributive, transpose-invariant, and differentiable
$$\eqalign{
 X:Y &= Y:X \cr
 X:(Y+Z) &= X:Y + X:Z \cr
 X:Y &= X^T:Y^T \cr
 d\,(X:Y) &= dX:Y + X:dY \cr
}$$
It also has simple mixed product rules for the Kronecker and Hadamard products
$$\eqalign{
 (A\otimes B):(X\otimes Y) &= (A:X)\otimes(B:Y) \cr
 (A\circ B):C &= A:(B\circ C) \cr
}$$
And useful mixed product rules for the Matrix product
$$\eqalign{
 AX:Y &= X:A^TY \cr
 XB:Y &= X:YB^T \cr
}$$